# Java split giving opposite order of arabic characters

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, split, arabic

I am splitting the following string using `\\|` in java (android) using the IntelliJ 12 IDE.

[image]

Everything is fine except the last part, somehow the split picks them up in the opposite order :

[image]

As you can see the real positioning `34,35,36` is correct and according to the string, but when it gets picked out into `split part no 5` its in the wrong order, `36,35,34` ...

Any way I can get them to be in the right order?

My Code:

```
public ArrayList<Book> getBooksFromDatFile(Context context, String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    try
    {
        // load csv from assets
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] RowData = line.split("\\|");
                books.add(new Book(RowData[0], RowData[1], RowData[2], RowData[3], RowData[4], RowData[5]));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing csv file!");
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error closing input stream!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading .dat file from assets!");
    }

    return books;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure real positions of characters 34, 35, and 36 are correct?  If that substring is supposed to represent "one through seven," shouldn't the '١' be at position 34 and the '٧' be at position 36?

Comment: VGR, yes but remember its arabic so its right to left, even with the numbers. So 36 is the first thing to be read in arabic. When I displayed it in normal TextView without any special RTL setting I hoped it would just look right.

Comment: Right-to-left characters are *rendered* right to left, but in a String, they are always in linguistic order.  Characters should not be placed in a String in reverse order to get them rendered right-to-left;  rendering engines take care of that.  The first character is '١', regardless of whether it is rendered on the left or on the right.

Comment: @VGR you are absolutely right. Please make your comment an answer if you want it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in the String should always be in linguistic order, regardless of whether they're right-to-left or left-to-right characters.  So we should see [34] = '١', [35] = '-', [36] = '٧'.  It is up to rendering engines to display them using the correct right-to-left or left-to-right layout.

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode world, there are strong and weak characters. These are the list of weak characters:

```
 "\\", "/", "+", "-", "=", ";", "$"
```

They are called "weak" characters because they do not contain any directional information. So it is up to the software to decide in which direction these "weak" characters will be placed, [more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text).
To fix this issue you need to set the [Directional Formatting](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls), for example:

```
RightToLeftEmbedding + weakCharacter + PopDirectionalFormatting
```

using these constant values

```
 char RightToLeftEmbedding = (char)0x202B;
 char PopDirectionalFormatting = (char)0x202C;
```